# Error: Extracting Data from Request Body in MongoDB Serverless Function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, base64, serverless

When working with a MongoDB serverless function, I encountered a challenge while trying to extract data from the request body. The process resulted in unexpected errors that needed to be addressed in order to properly handle the data.

Upon attempting to access the data from the request body using body.Data, an error occurred. Despite the presence of data in the body, the method of retrieval triggered the error, preventing successful extraction.

I encountered an issue while attempting to extract data from the body of a request, which resulted in errors. To address this problem, I made an attempt to retrieve the body data separately.

Here is the code snippet I used for my MongoDB serverless function:

The problem arises when trying to access the data from the body

`Sample code for the MongoDB serverless function`

```
  exports = async function({ query, headers, body }, response) {
  const  bodyData = body.Data;
  
  return { body, bodyData };
};
```

An error occurs when attempting to retrieve data using `body.Data`

`

```
{
  "body": {
    "Subtype": 0,
    "Data": "W3sNCiAgImV4Y2VycHQiOiAiTmV3IEV4Y2VycHQiLA0KICAiZGVzY3JpcHRpb24iOiAiTmV3IERlc2NyaXB0aW9uIiwNCiAgImltYWdlVXJsMSI6ICJodHRwczovL2V4YW1wbGUuY29tL2ltYWdlLmpwZyIsDQogICJpbWFnZVVybDIiOiAiaHR0cHM6Ly9leGFtcGxlLmNvbS9pbWFnZTIuanBnIiwNCiAgImltYWdlVXJsMyI6ICJodHRwczovL2V4YW1wbGUuY29tL2ltYWdlMy5qcGciLA0KICAiZGF0ZSI6ICIyMDIzLTA3LTE0IiwNCiAgImNhdGVnb3J5IjogIlRlY2hub2xvZ3kiLA0KICAidHJlbmRpbmciOiB0cnVlLA0KICAidG9wUGljayI6IGZhbHNlLA0KICAicG9wdWxhciI6IHRydWUNCn1d"
  },
  "bodyData": {}
}
```

`

There is data available in the body. However, accessing the data through `body.Data` is causing an error

Answer (score 2):

The issue you encountered might be related to the format of the data in the request body. It appears that the body.Data value is a Base64-encoded string. To access the actual data, you need to decode the Base64 string.

Updated code:

```
exports = async function({ query, headers, body }, response) {
  const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(body.Data, 'base64');
  const decodedData = dataBuffer.toString('utf8');
  
  return { body, decodedData };
};
```

Now, when you access decodedData, it should contain the decoded data from the Base64 string in the request body. Make sure to use decodedData instead of bodyData in your further processing.

Comment: Upon running the code, I received an error message indicating a "FunctionExecutionError." "error": "{\"message\":\"First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.\",\"name\":\"TypeError\"}",
  "error_code": "FunctionExecutionError", I have thoroughly investigated the error and attempted various troubleshooting steps, but unfortunately, the issue persists.

Comment: To provide further context, I would like to inform you about the data I sent during my testing. I used the following format:  

{
  "excerpt": "New Excerpt",
  "description": "New Description",
  "imageUrl1": "https://example.com/image.jpg",
  "imageUrl2": "https://example.com/image2.jpg",
  "imageUrl3": "https://example.com/image3.jpg",
  "date": "2023-07-14",
  "category": "Technology",
  "trending": true,
  "topPick": false,
  "popular": true
}

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the error code/issue I asked before!

Here's how I solved the issue:

```js
exports = async function({ query, headers, body }, response) {
    const result = JSON.parse(body.text())
    return { result };
}
```

I hope this helps others who encounter the same problem.